# Получить ответ от сервера WebKit2GTK C++

Tags: c++, linux, webkit

Пишу авторизацию бота на YouTube через свой браузер (WebKit) и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Согласно [документации](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps), сервер после авторизации перенаправит клиента на указанный redirect_uri и отправит ему JSON с инфой о токене.
 В моем случае перенаправит на 127.0.0.1. Но так как там нету (и не планируется запускать) веб сервера, который мог бы отдать код браузеру (WebKit), получается connection refused.
 Из-за этого я не вижу, что мне ответил сервер ютуба.
Я искал способ взять у вебкита ответ сервера, но не нашел. Возможно плохо искал.
Прошу помощи

Comment: В документации упоминаются `Manual copy/paste` и `Programmatic extraction`, может они Вам лучше подойдут ?

Comment: @vt-egorov 5, в документации также сказано, что оба эти варианта не рекомендуются к использованию, так как "есть более удобные и надежные методы"

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я упустил одну деталь в документации. Сервер на стадии предоставления резрешения дает не `access_token`, а `authorization_code`, который необходим для получения `access_token` в следующем запросе.

То есть, вот правильный порядок действий:

1. Формируется запрос на `accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` для предоставления юзером прав для бота.
2. Ответом сервера будет перенаправление на `127.0.0.1` с `authorization_code` в адресе. Он не шлет никакой JSON в этом шаге. ([Блок в документации об этом](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#sample-authorization-urls))
3. Формируется запрос на `oauth2.googleapis.com/token` с использованием `authorization_code`.
4. В ответ приходит JSON с `access_token`, который используется дальше в вызовах API YouTube. ([Блок в документации об этом](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#exchange-authorization-code))